# node1 was not declared in this scope c++ data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures

**I am making this program in data-structures and i get the following error that node1 is not declared in this scope also head was not declared in this scope and size also null i dont understand what the problem is**

```
#include<iostream>

    #include<conio.h>

    using namespace std;


            struct node // I have created the struct of node here

            {

                int data;

                struct node *next;

            };

        int main() {

        node1;

        node1 *head;

        head = (node *) malloc(size of (node1));

        if(head=null)

        return;

        head->data=1;

        head->next=Null;

        head->next=(node*)malloc(size of(node1));

        head->next->data=2;

        head->next->next=Null;

        node1 *current=head;

            while(current!Null)

            {

                cout<<current->data;

                current=current->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you honestly think this was supposed to be valid C++ code?

Comment: Yes. This is a C++ code

Comment: `#include<conio.h>` are people still using Turbo c++ ??

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node
{
/*
*/
}; 

node1 head;
```

node isn't node1;
also, it's C, not C++

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined *node1*? You have a struct named *node*. Also if you want to use *node* in your code instead of *struct node* everywhere, I recommend you usea typedef as:

`typedef struct node {
//your node data members
}node;`